# How to share from React Native to Instagram?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native to create an iOS app. However i would like to share a uri to an S3 video as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Share, Linking ....} from 'react-native'

//button and run function
testShareInsta = async () => {
     const uri = "https://s3-dev.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/video/myvideo";
     let encodedURL = encodeURIComponent(uri);  
     let instagramURL = 'instagram://library?AssetPath=${encodedURL}';
     return Linking.openURL(instagramURL);
  }
```

What can i do to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i open an S3 link to share to Instagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748137/how-do-i-open-an-s3-link-to-share-to-instagram)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download video using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)
2. Store your video to camera roll using [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera)
3. Share your video to instagram using [@react-native-social-share/instagram](https://github.com/r0b0t3d/react-native-social-share/tree/master/packages/instagram). **Disclaimer**: I am the owner of this lib

Comment: Hi, Tuan. I already have my video in an S3 bucket. So the URL is already available with a video ready to be shared. I don't need to share anything from my camera roll. Can this method be used for that?

Comment: As my understanding, Instagram do not allow you to share url. You could refer here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/#shareable-content

Comment: @TuanLuong is it possible to put image desciption when sharing image with your library ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
import Share from 'react-native-share';

const options = {
  title: 'XYZ',
  message:"HELLO",
  social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM,
};
const shareResponse = await Share.shareSingle(options);
```